# click on Back Arrow in Toolbar programmatically

Tags: java, android, android-activity, fragment, toolbar

hi i have an activity and I display 2 frigments I want to automatically close the toolbar when the back button is clicked

How can I do this? Should the code be written in an activity or in a fragment?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it in an activity:

```
boolean toolbarIsOpened = false;

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (toolbarIsOpened){
        //closeToolbar
        toolbar.animate().translationY(-toolbar.getBottom()).setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator()).start();
    }else{
        int count = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();

        if (count == 0) {
            super.onBackPressed();
        } else {
            getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        }
    }
}
```

Another way to hide:

```
getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

Press "back arrow" programmatically:

```
onBackPressed();
```

Comment: i know how to use onBackPressed but i dont know how to close toolbar

Comment: @git please, provide xml-code or java-code of toolbar implementation

Comment: It is a custom Toolbar widget or default?

Comment: I updated the post Please see the attached image
The toolbar is the default

Comment: this code hide toolbar but Items are still selected       `toolbar.animate().translationY(-toolbar.getBottom()).setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator()).start();` I want to click on the back arrow button with coding

Comment: @git to press back arrow programmatically, just call method: onBackPressed();

Comment: after this, you need to handle ```public void onBackPressed() {}```

Comment: `onBackPressed();` closed app i handled onBackPressed func but not worked

Answer (score 0):

You can use `performclick` method like below snippets

```
img_back.performClick();
```